# Use FFMPEG to put images separately inside a "box" and keeping their original positions of the X and Y boundaries and maybe modify their offsets

Tags: image, image-processing, ffmpeg

I have a collection of images, for this example, I created 3 images that have different sizes, but the image itsself is the same, except it is moved more down or left or right.

1: [image] 2: [image] 3: [image]

These are the images. The total sizes of all images together is 35x39, so that means that they need to go inside an 35x39 image so it can later be used to craft them into a GIF as example. Since "crop" does not really work as it crops it smaller and can't make them bigger and I can't imagine it being the best solution for that anyway, perhaps.

So this is the invisible 35x39 sized box.

image: [image]

So what I'm trying to do is to figure out how I can put each of these images separately in the 35x39 sized box, but maintaining the original X position or the Y position or both, from the boundaries of the images. I'm trying to figure out how I can do this for other transparent images for similar things, mostly used to craft animations. Here into a GIF out of image collections, but the images need to be fixed first.

I tried to look in the FFMPEG documentation, but there's many many filters and etc. that I had a few issues finding the right thing. I'm also not sure if it is also then possible to change the offset of the X and Y, because I think if there's something to make it keep the original position of X and Y, then I also think that there's probably something to change the offset of it aswell.

End result of the images could basically be:

1: [image] 2: [image] 3: [image]

This end result example of the images, basically have their X aligned on the top and Y aligned on the left. I'm not sure if you can call it "original X position", because if I compare it to Photoshop's special paste and keep at original position, it puts the first image a bit more down as example, for some reason. So I just moved the X all the way to the top and the Y all the way to the left.

Comment: I've read it three times and can't understand what you are trying to do. Nor can I understand why your possible solution is a solution - I thought you wanted to put 3 images in a box and keep expecting to find a solution with a box with 3 images in it rather than three separate images. Confused 

Comment: Nah, I actually want them to be in separate 3 images, lemme write "separate images". Example, here is to craft them into a gif later, but their positions need to be fixed.
The possible solution is "how it should look like", because someone once asked for clarification, on how it should look like at the end. And since those are only 3 images I put them somehow and moved them up until the boundaries reached the top.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've edited it now.

Comment: You say *"the total size of all the images together is 35x39"*. Do you mean you want them to somehow fit in a box whose width is given by the width of the widest image and whose height is given by the tallest image?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yep, 35 is the largest width that appears in that image collection and 39 the largest height that appears in that image collection

Comment: So, basically you want to expand each of the images to the same size. The new size will be the width of the widest of the three and the height will be the height of the tallest. The expansion is to be made by adding transparent areas to the bottom and right sides of the original image till it reaches the new size.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Not transparent areas, actually. The images boundaries, each of the image have boundaries with extra space in it. This extra space needs to stay, that's why the images boundaries